# Windows XP command issue

Tags: windows-xp

I can't use the command "certreq" in window command prompt, could someone advise how to make this command available in window command prompt?

Should I add a path in system environment or something else?

The error message as below

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C: \ Documents and Settings \ user> cd C: \ iOS

C: \ iOS> certreq-new certreq.txt newcsr.pem
'certreq' is not an internal or external command,
Operable program or batch file.

C: \ iOS> certreq
'certreq' is not an internal or external command,
Operable program or batch file.

C: \ iOS>
```

Thanks

Comment: -1 for not even showing the command used nor the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certreq command can be used as follows:

Certreq [-submit] [-retrieve RequestID] [-new] [-accept] [-policy]
[-sign] [-attrib AttributeString] [-binary]
[-config CAMachineName\CAName] [-crl] [-rpc] [-cert CertID]
[RequestFileIn | CertChainFileIn | FullResponseFileIn | CertFileIn | PolicyFileIn]
[RequestFileOut | CertChainFileOut | FullResponseFileOut | CertFileOut | PKCS10FileOut]

for more reference u can refer to
[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725793%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Probably your version is not compatible to use certreq command...i prefer u use [openssl](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#intro-version) command
u can go to the link for more details of the parameters u may use to get your required certificated request done....
hope it helps.....:)

Comment: Sorry i have posted the answer but were u actually looking for how to use it or is there a problem in using it coz u havent mentioned the error......

Comment: Thanks, I got other option to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, certreq.exe ships with the server editions of Windows. I am assuming you're using the desktop variants.

As an alternative, I suggest the use of `openssl` to generate certificates. Check out [the documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html) for more details.